# Solving an Algebraic Equation with Constraints on Multiple Parameters

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

Suppose we have the following equation to solve (with respect to $x$):

$$
\frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2} + \frac{m\alpha x^3}{3} = E,\quad\text{where }m,\omega,\alpha,E>0\text{ and } E < \frac{m\omega^6}{6\alpha^2}. 
$$

Now, theoretically speaking, along with these constraints, we should have derived 3 real roots for this equation. But when I tried to actually solve it on Mathematica, whether I had added these constraints in the `Assumptions` field, it kept giving me the complex roots. What am I supposed to do to let Mathematica derive the desired real roots? Any of your help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: `Reduce[(m*ω^2*x^2)/2 + (m*α*x^3)/3 == e && 
  m > 0 &&  ω > 0 && α > 0 && e > 0 && 
  e < (m*ω^6)/(6 α^2), Reals]
`

Comment: `Solve[(m*ω^2*x^2)/2 + (m*α*x^3)/3 == e && 
  m > 0 &&  ω > 0 && α > 0 && e > 0 && 
  e < (m*ω^6)/(6 α^2), Reals]
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(An applied mathematician's take, too long for a comment.)

In problems like these it helps to do **scaling** (also called **non-dimensionalisation**) to reduce the number of parameters.

Dividing through by the maximum energy $m \omega^6 / (6 \alpha^2)$, we have
$$
  \frac{3 \alpha^2 x^2}{\omega^4} + \frac{2 \alpha^3 x^3}{\omega^6} = \hat{E}
  \tag{1}
$$
where
$$
  \hat{E} = \left. E \middle/ \frac{m \omega^6}{6 \alpha^2} \right.
$$
is the dimensionsless energy. Inspecting $(1)$, we see that it is sensible to define the dimensionless position
$$
  \hat{x} = \frac{\alpha x}{\omega^2},
$$
so that the problem reduces to
$$
  3 \hat{x}^2 + 2 \hat{x}^3 = \hat{E}, \qquad 0 < \hat{E} < 1.
$$

After this simplification, Mathematica is able to return a result with radicals, even without specifying any assumptions. Note that we have [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis); **all three roots are real**, but a pair of them can only be expressed in terms of radicals using complex numbers.

```
Solve[3 xHat^2 + 2 xHat^3 == eHat, xHat]
```

$$
\small
\left\{\left\{\hat{x}\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{\hat{E}^2-\hat{E}}+2 \hat{E}-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{\hat{E}^2-\hat{E}}+2 \hat{E}-1}}-1\right)\right\},\left\{\hat{x}\to -\frac{1}{4} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{\hat{E}^2-\hat{E}}+2 \hat{E}-1}-\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{4 \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{\hat{E}^2-\hat{E}}+2 \hat{E}-1}}-\frac{1}{2}\right\},\left\{\hat{x}\to -\frac{1}{4} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{\hat{E}^2-\hat{E}}+2 \hat{E}-1}-\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{4 \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{\hat{E}^2-\hat{E}}+2 \hat{E}-1}}-\frac{1}{2}\right\}\right\}
$$

Also of note is that the three roots lie in the interval $-3/2 < \hat{x} < 1/2$:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[{3 xHat^2 + 2 xHat^3, eHat}, {xHat, -3/2, 1/2}]
  , {{eHat, 1/2}, 0, 1}
]
```

[image: Visualising the three roots in a Manipulate]

Comment: Express xHat without complex numbers: `Solve[3 xHat^2 + 2 xHat^3 == eHat, xHat] // 
  ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
 Simplify[#, 0 < eHat < 1] & `  . Yields `{{xHat -> -(1/2) + 
    Cos[1/3 ArcTan[-1 + 2 eHat, 2 Sqrt[(1 - eHat) eHat]]]}, {xHat -> 
   1/2 (-1 - Cos[1/3 ArcTan[-1 + 2 eHat, 2 Sqrt[(1 - eHat) eHat]]] - 
      Sqrt[3] Sin[
        1/3 ArcTan[-1 + 2 eHat, 2 Sqrt[(1 - eHat) eHat]]])}, {xHat -> 
   1/2 (-1 - Cos[1/3 ArcTan[-1 + 2 eHat, 2 Sqrt[(1 - eHat) eHat]]] + 
      Sqrt[3] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[-1 + 2 eHat, 2 Sqrt[(1 - eHat) eHat]]])}} ` .

Comment: @Akku14 Ah yes, complex radicals can be eliminated in favour of trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

A cubic equation has exactly 3 roots. There are not 3 real and 3 complex roots! Could it be, that there is a misunderstanding in the interpretation of what MMA gives you? If you use `Solve` and apply the restrictions of the solution, you will get real numbers (note that the may have multiplicity >1). Let's make an example:

```
sol = Solve[(m*ω^2*x^2)/2 + (m*α*x^3)/3 == e && 
   m > 0 && ω > 0 && α > 0 && e > 0 && 
   e < (m*ω^6)/(6 α^2), x, Reals]
```

This gives the following result:

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-6 e + 3 m ω^2 #1^2 + 2 m α #1^3 &, 1], 
    e > 0 && 
     m > (6 e α^2)/ω^6 && α > 0 && ω > 
      0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-6 e + 3 m ω^2 #1^2 + 2 m α #1^3 &, 2], 
    e > 0 && 
     m > (6 e α^2)/ω^6 && α > 0 && ω > 
      0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-6 e + 3 m ω^2 #1^2 + 2 m α #1^3 &, 3], 
    e > 0 && 
     m > (6 e α^2)/ω^6 && α > 0 && ω > 
      0]}}
```

Could it be that you are not happy with `Root` objects and call them "complex"? Well, a root object simply means a root of the given polynomial. You may always evaluate roots to approximate machine numbers by using `N`.

We now choose some numerical values, taking care of the conditions. E.g.:

```
sol /. {m -> 7, α -> 1, ω -> 1, e -> 1} // N
*{{x -> -1.2047}, {x -> -0.762103}, {x -> 0.466801}}*)
```

You see, we get 3 real solutions for x.

Comment: Maybe you can try out this for mathematica code : http://steampiano.net/msc/

Comment: @wuyudi Thanks for the hint